# How to accurately display a decimal number?

Tags: javascript, decimal

Probably this is a duplicate of a question asked before, but I could not find the answer.
I am using javascript and trying to display the number p1*10^p2, where p1 is a positive integer and p2 is an integer (negative or positive).
Unfortunately, because of the binary representation of numbers, the following function does not work.

```
function toDisplay(p1, p2) {return p1*Math.pow(10, p2);}
```

It often returns a long decimal number, which is only an approximate value of the exact form I need. Can someone please help me modify this function? All I need is to shift the decimal point in p1 by p2 places (left or right, depending on the sign of p2) and adding 0s as needed. I need a string as an answer. I tried to do this, but I could not figure out how to make it work.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js/, you may want to look at this.

Comment: Can you provide some example? Like p1 = ?, p2 = ? and the result you want to get from those input values?

Comment: integers don't carry decimal's, so there's your problem

Comment: For example, if p1=341 and p2=-5, I need 0.00341 and not 0.0034999999

Comment: Floating point can't represent most decimal fractions exactly. That's as close as it can get.

Comment: Since you're just working with powers of 10, you can just add 0's to either end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're dealing with powers of 10, and you're only concerned with displaying them in decimal, this would work:

```
function repeatStr(s, n){
    // returns s, repeated n times.
    if(String.prototype.repeat){
        return s.repeat(n);
    }
    var res = "";
    for(var i=0; i<n; i++){
        res += s; 
    }
    return res
}

function getDecimal(p1, p2) {
    // returns the decimal representation, as a string, of p1*10^p2.
    p1 = p1.toString();
    if (p2 === 0) {
        return p1  //p1*10^0 == p1*1 == p1.
    }
    if(p2 > 0) {
        // multiplying by 10^p2 just adds p2 0's.
        return p1 + repeatStr("0", p2); 
    } else {
        // p1 is negative, so we have (-p2)-1 0's after the decimal point.
        return "0." + repeatStr("0", (p2*-1) - 1) + p1;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. BTW, in case p2 gets large, there's a faster way to implement RepeatSTR: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat#Polyfill. I used this version because it's shorter and clearer, and string repetition is not the point of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Math.round(number * 100000) / 100000`

Answer (score 0):

Well, hope you don't hate `eval`

```
function toDisplay(p1, p2) {
    return eval(p1 + 'e' + p2);
}
```

That returns a float number. You can do `+ ""` to make the it a string.